# Kodi Plugin structure is incorrect

Tags: python, macos, plugins, kodi

I'm having a trouble packaging Kodi plugin under MAC. I took as an example a simple video plugin and wanted to start with a simple renaming before doing further development. At this stage, import of plugin constantly fails when I do

Install from Zip in Kodi

I've resolved all issue related to specific MAC zip content, by writing my own python ZIP script, [which omits all MAC related files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286113/xbmc-kodi-error-adding-addon-structure-incorrect). Thus, now I can unzip and zip a working plugin and successfully import it in Kodi. However, i'm still having `Addon does not have correct structure`.

Here is a [link to my custom plugin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ic4ljm3h1i0yhgg/plugin.video.telemachus.zip?dl=0).

What strikes me the most is that simple renaming causes all these issues. You might know any debugging tool for Kodi plugins? I will greatly appreciate any assistance, since I have put already 3 days in it.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? i have same issue under windows !

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, there seems to be a bug in Kodi, whenever you try to load a plugin with an incorrect structure, all subsequent loads will fails as well, even if the structure the updated plugin is correct. You should restart KODI to resolve this.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I was really stuck until I found this.